# Arcpy SplitRaster crashes. How to debug?

Tags: python-2.7, arcgis, arcpy

When running the following script, the application is crashing. Any ideas why? or how to find the reason?

```
Import arcpy module
import arcinfo
import arcpy
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")
from arcpy import env
from arcpy.sa import *

# Local variables:
SLOPE10m = r"F:\AufbereitungCLC2006\LandnutzungInn.gdb\SLOPE10m"

# Set Geoprocessing environments
arcpy.env.scratchWorkspace = r"F:\AufbereitungCLC2006\Temp\ScratchWorkspace.gdb"
arcpy.env.parallelProcessingFactor = "8"
arcpy.env.cellSize = "MAXOF"
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

# Process: Split Raster
left = arcpy.GetRasterProperties_management(SLOPE10m , "LEFT")
bottom = arcpy.GetRasterProperties_management(SLOPE10m , "BOTTOM")
origin = str(left[0]) + " " + str(bottom[0])

arcpy.SplitRaster_management(SLOPE10m, r"F:\AufbereitungCLC2006\Temp\Splitraster", "slp10_", "SIZE_OF_TILE", "GRID", "BILINEAR", "#", "120000 120000", "1000", "METERS", "#", origin)
```

Thanks
Steffen

Comment: Can you please post an error message and/or stack trace?

Comment: `Runtime error  Traceback (most recent call last):   File "<string>", line 77, in <module>   File "f:\arcgis_installation\desktop10.3\arcpy\arcpy\management.py", line 14170, in SplitRaster     raise e ExecuteError: ERROR 001143: Background server threw an exception.`

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't recreate your error, but I did manage to make your script work on my machine. I would venture to say your issues lies within the [parallelProcessingFactor](http://resources.arcgis.com/de/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001w0000004m000000) setting as it spreads the workload across multiple cores which could cause a 'performance penalty'. Perhaps try a lower setting? I also made a few tweaks to your script.

Here's what I did:

```
import arcpy
arcpy.env.workspace = True
arcpy.CheckOutExtension('Spatial')
arcpy.parallelProcessingFactor = '8'
SLOPE10m = r'C:\raster'

left = arcpy.GetRasterProperties_management(SLOPE10m , 'LEFT')
bottom = arcpy.GetRasterProperties_management(SLOPE10m , 'BOTTOM')
origin = str(left[0]) + ' ' + str(bottom[0])
arcpy.SplitRaster_management(SLOPE10m, r'C:\raster', 'slp10_', 'SIZE_OF_TILE', 'GRID', 'BILINEAR', '#', '120000 120000', '1000', 'METERS', '#', origin)
```

I excluded some of your imports as I found them unnecessary along with the [cellSize](http://help.arcgis.com/EN/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001w0000001s000000) environment setting since the value you had is already the default setting. I hope that helps.